# 'ARIMA' object has no attribute 'forecast'

Tags: arima

### forecast = model.forecast(steps=82)[0]

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [135], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 forecast = model.forecast(steps=82)[0]

AttributeError: 'ARIMA' object has no attribute 'forecast'

Answer (score 1):

import library in statsmodel

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

use model with library stats model

```
model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(train_data, order=(1, 1, 1))  
fitted = model.fit()
print(fitted.summary())
```

and now your atrribute forecast can be used.